# appsettings configurations for enabling a group and subgroups

Tags: .net, .net-core, appsettings

Let's suppose I have an dotnet web api with controllers containing endpoints that we can consider each controller a subgroup and some of this subgroups belong to a bigger group.

Now I want to itemize the Api so that through app settings the Api can be easily itemizable.
I think this can be achieved with attributes that will read the settings. (still don't know if it's the best approach)

In terms of the settings I'm thinking in doing something like:

```
  "Enable_X": true,
  "X_groups": {
    "Enable_AAC": true,
    "Enable_A": true,
    "Enable_B": true,
    "Enable_O": true,
    "Enable_P": true
  },
  "Enable_CB": true,
  "CB_groups": {
    "Enable_FCC": true,
    "Enable_FC": true
  },
  "Enable_P": true,
  "P_groups": {
    "Enable_DDC": true,
    "Enable_DP": true
  }
```

Then the attributes assigned at controller level would take care of the rest.

Does this seem like a good approach?